# Смена endpoint внутри vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Является ли предосудительным использовать смену ednpoint внутри store (vuex), т.е.

```
await this.$router.push('/');
```

Сходу, кажется, что это нехорошо, потому как vuex занимается только лишь хранением данных. Но, при этом, я не знаю, чем это может грозить. В этом и заключается вопрос.

Основная задача заключается в том, чтобы избавиться от логики в компоненте.

я просто хочу максимально избавиться от кода в компонентах. Поэтому и думаю: оставить ли мне

```
    created: async function() {
        this.settings = this.$store.state.settings;
        this.course = this.$store.state.course;
        this.classes = this.$store.state.classes;
        if (Object.keys(this.course).length === 0 || this.classes.length === 0) {
            await this.$router.push('/');
        }
    },
```

Хочется полностью избавиться от логики в компоненте, т.е. от `if` или от более масштабных конструкций, которые могут встречаться в других местах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое разумное, что приходит в голову -- это вынести в helpers.js логику. Это  хорошо, поскольку там она может быть протестирована. В компоненте в явном виде это сделать на порядке сложнее. В частности, unit-тесты сделать нельзя и можно только протестировать функционально, с помощью утилит вроде selenium.